# NameError: Uninitialized Constant though model is located under /app/models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I am writing a class file called Ticket.rb in order to create a Scumblr workflow. I have this file saved under /app/models, but when I try to execute the below line of code, I get a NameError: uninitialized constant Ticket:

```
ticket = Ticket.create(summary=>"Test ticket")
```

The above line of code is executed on the rails console.

The code for the class file (/app/models/Ticket.rb) is below:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_workflowable
end
```

The error that I get looks like this on the console:

```
[5] pry(main)> ticket = Ticket.create(summary=>"Test ticket")
NameError: uninitialized constant Ticket
from (pry):5:in `__pry__'
```

Also, I am following the tutorial that can be found here to set up the workflow:
https://github.com/Netflix/Workflowable/wiki

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Ruby on Rails and I've made sure that I followed the tutorial exactly until the Ticket.create line of code, but I'm not sure if there is something that is not mentioned in the tutorial and that's where I'm going wrong. I haven't seen anything that would address this issue on Stack Overflow and I could really use some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you trying to execute this code? in the rails console?

Comment: Yes, first I ran rails c to open up the console, then I ran the Ticket.create line.

Comment: add it is, summary is a constant.  Symbolize it, puting a colon `:` before it `:summary=>...`

Comment: @MukundK. will you pls post all error lines?

Comment: or if you use ruby > 1.9: `Ticket.create summary: "Test`

Comment: post output of this command over here.

Comment: @Hitesh. I added the output above. Also, neither the colon nor the ruby > 1.9 seem to solve the issue. The error is the same.

Comment: Another guess: The Uppercase filename could cause problems, what rails version are you using?

Comment: @RaVeN: Thank you so much! I did not think of that, and now it seems to be almost working. I am getting an error that says "NameError: undefined local variable or method `summary' for main:Object", which I think just means I need to declare a local String variable? Also, I am using Rails 4.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you named the file `Ticket.rb` and not `ticket.rb`.

And you'll have to change the line:

```
ticket = Ticket.create(summary=>"Test ticket")
```

to

```
ticket = Ticket.create(summary: "Test ticket")
```

unless you have `summary` defined in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work cuz you fogot `:` to summary

```
ticket = Ticket.create(:summary=>"Test ticket")
#but the best code be like
ticket = Ticket.create(summary: 'Test ticket')
```